# Startup script to decrypt home directory

Tags: linux-mint, startup, ecryptfs

I accidentally enabled `/home` encryption on installation. So I need to decrypt it manually from console after every system start. I do it with `ecryptfs-umount-private`. How can I make the decryption automatically at startup?

Comment: I edited the text and title to read "decrypt" instead of "encrypt" since this is what I assume you meant. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could decrypt it permanently, using :

[this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4950/how-to-stop-using-built-in-home-directory-encryption) (inspired by [this other post](http://ubuntu-ky.ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=8867369&postcount=10)) :

> 1. Backup the home directory while you are logged in
>      `sudo cp -rp /home/user /home/user.backup`
>
>    > 1.1. Check that your home backup has everything!!!
> 2. reboot into root via grub
>
>    > OR you could just switch to using root (another user account with `sudo` privileges would work equally well).
> 3. Delete your home directory `rm -rf /home/user`
> 4. Remove `/home/.ecryptfs/<myusername>`
>
>    > Then remove the packages `apt-get remove ecryptfs-utils libecryptfs0`
> 5. Restore your home directory `mv /home/user.backup /home/user`
> 6. reboot
> 7. Remove any of those `.Private` `.ecryptfs` folders `rm -rf ~/.Private` `rm -rf ~/.ecryptfs`
> 8. Yay!
>
> This worked for me. Home folder file permissions stay intact and does not bugger up Dropbox or git repos. Some reason my fresh  install on Ubuntu 9.10 would not do the first command.

Comment: it seems pretty cool. can I backup my '/home' directory and then restore it on newly installed system?

Comment: If you create a brand new install, you should create a user with the same username than before (it will add data (user name, password hash,...) to the /etc/shadow file). Then, using the root, restore the /home directory. It should work IMO, but I haven't tested it yet (while the above solution has been tested). In any case, if you already have some important data file (your work, photos,...) in your home, it'd safe to back it up on a separate device.