# How to solve $HOME/.dmrc file permission error?

Tags: permissions, linux-mint, home

I recently had a problem and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/454260/startup-script-to-decrypt-home-directory) is the solution of it. After following these steps I fixed my problem, but faced another one.

On Login window after I enter my password and press `Enter`, this message popups:

> `User's $HOME/.dmrc file is being ignored. This prevents the default
>   session and language from being saved. File should be owned by user
>   and have 644 permissions. User's $HOME directory must be owned by user
>   and not writable by other users.`

I haven't noticed any notable problems except of this message, but anyway, how to solve it?

```
ls -ld "$HOME" "$HOME/.dmrc"
drwxr-xr-x 82 neo neo 4096 Jul 12 12:05 /home/neo
-rw------- 1 neo neo 29 Jul 12 12:05 /home/neo/.dmrc
```

I have tried [this](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/%93user%92s-%24home-dmrc%94-file-is-being-ignored-589557/#post2913943) but it had no effect.

Comment: @Kusalananda `$ ls -ld "$HOME" "$HOME/.dmrc"  


drwxr-xr-x 82 neo neo 4096 Jul 12 12:05 /home/neo  


-rw-------  1 neo neo   29 Jul 12 12:05 /home/neo/.dmrc
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your permissions and ownerships of `$HOME` and of `$HOME/.dmrc`, the only thing you need to do to satisfy the required ownership/permission settings is

```
chmod 644 "$HOME/.dmrc"
```

You already own your home directory and it's not writable by other users. The only thing not "correct" is that permissions on the `.dmrc` file are too tight.

Answer (score -1):

Googling around I found [this](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=976610) post. It stands for:

> ...
>
> Solution Summary: No Frills Depending on the problem, all of these
>   steps may not be necessary. Running all of them will correct any of
>   the issues addressed by the error message. They can be run in terminal
>   in the current session or from the root prompt in recovery mode. If
>   running from the root prompt, `sudo` is not required. These commands
>   will not work from the LiveCD desktop without modification . 
>   
>   `sudo chown username /home/username/.dmrc 
>   chmod 644 /home/username/.dmrc 
>   sudo chown username /home/username     # if you get a ".gvfs" error message, see Section 3, Note 3 
>   chmod 755 /home/username`
>
> Log out of your current session and back in. 
>   Rebooting is not necessary but will accomplish the same thing.
>
> For the last command, other acceptable permissions include 750 or 700.

Comment: Not strictly accurate as quoted here. Those asterisks around `username` could affect other users' files and directories, and the lack of semicolons between commands will mean the sequence as written here will fail to run usefully at all. (Note that the original document is accurate.)